# Rings where every indecomposable principal right ideal is extensive

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a (commutative or non-commutative, associative) unital ring. Following Nicholson & Yousif [1, p. 21], we say that a right ideal $\mathfrak i$ of $R$ is *extensive* if every $R$-linear function $\varphi \colon \mathfrak i \to R$ extends to an $R$-linear function $\bar{\varphi}: R \to R$. Accordingly, we call $R$

- *right principally injective* (or *right PI*) if every principal right ideal (PRI) of $R$ is extensive;
- *right principally indinjective* if every indecomposable PRI of $R$ is extensive;
- *right mininjective* if every simple right ideal of $R$ is extensive.

Right mininjective rings and right principally injective rings are extensively discussed in [1] (in particular, see Chs. 2 and 5). But I couldn't find anything about right indinjective rings (neither in the book nor elsewhere), probably because the term "principally indjective" (which I'm using here) is not the term commonly employed to refer to these objects. And this leads to the following:

> **Question.** Is there any standard terminology for what I'm calling a "right principally indinjective ring"? And in any case, could you suggest any reference where to read about these objects?

Since every simple right ideal of $R$ is a PRI, it is clear that
$$
\{\textrm{right PI}\} \subseteq \{\textrm{right principally indinjective rings}\} \subseteq \{\textrm{right mininjective}\},
$$

and I believe both inclusions are strict.

**Bibliography.**

[1] W.K. Nicholson and M.F. Yousif, *Quasi-Frobenius Rings*, Cambrige Tracts in Math. **158**, Cambridge Univ. Press, 2003.